# How to get into screen session?

Tags: linux, session, unix, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I've started several sessions in screen. Now I want to get into one of them. I've read [manual](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) about screen and since that I could see screen sessions list via

```
screen -list
```

So, now I know what session I want to get into, because I know its creation time and the above command showed me a list of sessions with their creation times.

Can one tell me how can I get into specific screen session to see its output and to send it commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reattach to the session:

```
screen -r <session_id>
```

**Example:**

1. Create a session, give it a nice name:

   ```
   user:~$ screen -S nananananana_batman
   ```
2. Close the terminal (detach).
3. List the active sessions:

   ```
   user:~$ screen -list

   There is a screen on:
       3151.nananananana_batman    (10/23/2013 05:34:02 PM)    (Detached)
   1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.
   ```
4. Reattach back to our session:

   ```
   user:~$ screen -S nananananana_batman
   ```

Comment: So, getting into the session is just reattaching to it?

Comment: If the screen is attached to a terminal somewhere, you might need to detach it (`-d`) first.

Comment: And how can I know session's id?

Comment: Unfortunatelly session is already created and it doesn't have a name

Comment: Use the ID of the session, not it's name.

Comment: I made it! Session's id is something written after digits and dot before next dot. If screen -list showed 4234.bla-bla.smthng then bla-bla is sessions id. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try out screen -x, i use it often when there is only one screen session.

It can also be used to attach a session where you forgot to detach/lost connection etc.

screen -R will try to attach the youngest session.